# 403 forbidden error worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, http-status-code-403

i have done a worklight mobile application .i have to create an artifact in the jazz.net server in my space .
i have used some links in the rest client then i am able to create an artifact in jazz server in my project space.

where as now i am using worklight and sending the same request it is giving me the forbidden 
error

{"responseID":"74","statusCode":403,"errors":[],"isSuccessful":true,"statusReason":"Forbidden","responseHeaders":{"Content-Language":"en-US","Date":"Wed, 22 May 2013 11:37:18 GMT","Content-Length":"571","X-jazzweb1":"D=780029 t=1369222638020906","Keep-Alive":"timeout=5, max=100","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Type":"application/rdf+xml; charset=UTF-8","Server":"IBM_HTTP_Server","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Proxy-Connection":"Keep-Alive"},"RDF":{"Description":{"errorMessage":{"CDATA":"Forbidden","datatype":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"},"detailedMessage":{"CDATA":"CRRRS6401E Error parsing content. Content must be valid rdf+xml.","datatype":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"},"errorStatus":{"CDATA":"403","datatype":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long"}},"err":"http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/foundation/1.0/","rdf":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"},"warnings":[],"totalTime":2584,"responseTime":2583,"info":[]}

my code is as below

```
function create(folderId)
 { var Request = '<rdf:RDFxmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/""xmlns:oslc_rm="http://open-services.net/ns/rm#" ><rdf:Description rdf:about=""><rdf:type rdf:resource="http://open-services.net/ns/rm#Requirement"/><dc:description rdf:parseType="Literal">OSLC artifact created</dc:description><dc:title rdf:parseType="Literal">OSLC Created Requirement anil</dc:title><oslc:instanceShape rdf:resource="https://jazz.net/rm/types/_0kMQplV1EeC7_0yA"/><nav:parent rdf:resource="https://jazz.net/rm/folders/_cYBT0WSxEe5ZruQ"/></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF>'; var path ='rm/requirementFactory?projectURL=https://jazz.net/jts/process/project-areas/_xKDFBlV1EeC7_0yA';
 var winput = 
{ method : 'post', 
//returnedContentType : 'none',
 path : path,
 headers : { 'accept' : 'application/xml', 
'OSLC-Core-Version' : '2.0' },
 body:{ content: Request,
 contentType: 'application/rdf+xml;
 charset=utf-8' }
 };
 return WL.Server.invokeHttp(winput);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing in this line is wrong,

```
 { var Request = '<rdf:RDFxmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/""xmlns:oslc_rm="http://open-services.net/ns/rm#" ><rdf:Description rdf:about=""><rdf:type rdf:resource="http://open-services.net/ns/rm#Requirement"/><dc:description rdf:parseType="Literal">OSLC artifact created</dc:description><dc:title rdf:parseType="Literal">OSLC Created Requirement anil</dc:title><oslc:instanceShape rdf:resource="https://jazz.net/rm/types/_0kMQplV1EeC7_0yA"/><nav:parent rdf:resource="https://jazz.net/rm/folders/_cYBT0WSxEe5ZruQ"/></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF>'; var path ='rm/requirementFactory?projectURL=https://jazz.net/jts/process/project-areas/_xKDFBlV1EeC7_0yA';
```

It looks like you're not sending a valid document because of the missing spaces.  rdf:RDF xmlns...

```
 { var Request = '<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
```

Comment: hi @rooftop thanks for ur replay .but the rdf that i have send is the correct one .The same rdf is working in the rest client .May i know any  other reason for which it fails